# what's the difference when calling kill from a shell script or directly in the terminal

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, kill

I'm trying to kill a process by ID from this shell script.

```
# based on
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437602/shell-script-to-get-the-process-id-on-linux
output=`ps -ax|grep Ad[o]be\ After\ Effects\ CS6`;
# set -- parses the ps output into words,
# and $1 is the first word on the line
# which happens to be the process ID
set -- $output;
pid=$1;
echo "I'm about to kill process " $pid;
killall -SEGV $pid;
```

But that gives me that result

```
No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

When I use the same ID my script echoed and execute the command directly it does what it should.

```
kill -SEGV 50283
```

So whats the difference?
And what do I have to do to make my script behave as if it where 'me' (I think it's something with user rights)?

Comment: sry i see it now. the script uses killall instead of kill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script you say `killall` which looks for a process by name.  In your terminal you say `kill` which takes a PID.  The former is erroneous, though arguably you should use killall in your script instead of implementing something similar yourself.

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for your answer. I saw the error the moment I hit publish. m( thats why I call me ...theblind. But I tried also killall in the Terminal with the -SEGV flag and it did not do the same thing. The kill version forces After Effects to autosave the current project before quitting.