# How to get process information using pid with Java?

Tags: java, process, native, jna

I have the process id of a process. Can I get other information about process like CPU%, memory, exe name, etc?

I have seen that there is no built-in function to get all this. How to do this with Native?

Please help.

Comment: Not through the Java APIs.  You will need a JNI/JNA (native) solution

Answer (score 2):

Java is a platform independent platform. Its specification doesn't define anything about pid. So you cannot find a general/portable way to manipulate pid. Although it is not a good practice, you can make an implemenation for a specific platform.

On windows you can use `tasklist` to get the full list of PIDs and filter for the one you want.

On Unix/Linux system you can use `ps ax | grep` to get your information.

Answer (score 1):

Well, all of those information you can get from the OS. For example, the **task manager in Windows**.

What Java can offer you is, for example, the **thread dump**:

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jstack.exe PID >stack.txt
```

Or, the **heap dump**:

```
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/jmap.exe -dump:format=b,file=heap.bin PID
```

Answer (score 0):

In-built to java there is no API exposed for this to my knowledge:

But you can couple java with OS native command to fetch the info.

e.g.

Windows explore (tasklist): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545415(v=vs.85).aspx

Unix explore (ps): [Shell script to get the process ID on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437602/shell-script-to-get-the-process-id-on-linux)