# Shell Script for Killing PID

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, kill, fuser

I run a few processes that I created myself on my Ubuntu Server, and to kill them I run:

```
sudo fuser -n tcp PORT
kill -9 PID-DISPLAYED
```

Is there any way I can obtain the PID from a port using a shell script, then kill it by running the shell script.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `kill -9` only as a last resort. `kill -15` (also the default when no signal is given) should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fuser can kill it:

```
 -k, --kill
     Kill processes accessing the file. Unless changed
     with -SIGNAL, SIGKILL is sent. An fuser process
     never kills itself, but may kill other fuser processes.
     The effective user ID of the process executing fuser is
     set to its real user ID before attempting to kill.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using either killall, or pkill, either of which will close all processes of the type of argument you describe, for example:

```
killall firefox
```

Will kill all running instances of firefox.

See
[this link of pkill.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437602/shell-script-to-get-the-process-id-on-linux)