# Set the pid of a searched running process (ps -ea | grep <search>}) in shell

Tags: shell, ps

I am making a shell script where I run a process and I am searching for that process like this `ps -ea | grep <search_term>` and I can find that process fine, but I want to set the pid of that process to a variable in my shell script, then wait until that process is finished.  This is the type of thing I want:

```
PID= (returned and parsed value of "ps -ea | grep <search_term>")
echo $PID
wait $PID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PID=$(ps -ea | awk '/<search_term>/,NF=1')
```

[Shell script to get the process ID on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6437602/shell-script-to-get-the-process-id-on-linux)